# Pandas dataframe.cut(), but with alphanumeric "ranges"?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset with a `code` value:

| code | line_id | etc... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10522 | 1001 | ... |
| 45450 | 1002 | ... |
| J2122 | 1003. | ... |
| A1234. | 1004. | ... |

I want to sort it into buckets based on predefined code ranges, similarly to what you'd do with `dataframe.cut()`.  Problem is, some of these codes are alphanumeric.  For instance, one of the ranges might be `J1000 to J9999` (which would catch line 1003 above.)

Is there a way that `cut()` can be used with alphanumeric ranges? Or is there a simple method that a relative python/pandas newbie like myself hasn't stumbled upon yet?

Comment: You can try using  `range1=[(df["code"]>"somevalue") & (df["code"]<"somevalue")]` to get ranges with alphanumeric values.